Playing sequences of impartial games and "colourful Nim"
Are there any topics in combinatorial game theory for solving a sequence of impartial games, where the loser of each sub-game goes first in the next sub-game?
For example, I'm interested in variant of Nim where each object in a pile is either red or yellow. On your turn, you can remove as many objects as you like from the top of the pile, as long as they are all the same colour.

This particular configuration is a $\mathcal N$-position, because the first player can force the following sequence of moves:

Here:

The first pile is the initial configuration, before any moves are made
The first player takes the top red object from the pile
The second player has to take the remaining top red object
The first player takes all but one yellow object from the top of the pile
The second player has to take the remaining top yellow object
The first player wins by taking the remaining two red objects

If there were more than one pile, it works the same way. Now you have the choice of taking as many objects as you like from the top of any of the piles, but the objects you do take from each must all be of the same colour.
I'm interested in calculating the Grundy value for an arbitrary position. Let $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k)$ for $n_i \in \mathbb N_{> 0}$ denote a configuration with $n_1$ red objects at the bottom, followed by $n_2$ yellow objects, and alternating until there are $n_k$ objects of a particular colour at the top.
$(n_1)$ is the same as an ordinary Nim pile of size $n_1$, and so $\mathcal G(n_1) = n_1$.
I believe that the Grundy value for an arbitrary position $(n_1, \ldots, n_k)$ is given by
$$
\mathcal G(n_1, \ldots, n_{2k}) = \begin{cases}
n_{2k} - 1 &\text{if }&& n_{2k-1} > n_{2k}, \text{ or } \\
           &          && n_{2k-2} < n_{2k-1} = n_{2k}, \text{ or } \\
           &          && n_{2k-3} > n_{2k-2} = n_{2k - 1} = n_{2k}, \text{ or } \\
           &          && \text{...and so on, alternating leading inequality until...} \\
           &          && n_1 \ge n_2 = n_3 = n_4 = \cdots = n_{2k} \\
n_{2k}     & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
for an even number of colour alternations, and for an odd number of colour alternations:
$$
\mathcal G(n_1, \ldots, n_{2k-1}) = \begin{cases}
n_{2k-1} - 1 &\text{if }&& n_{2k-2} > n_{2k-1}, \text{ or } \\
             &          && n_{2k-3} < n_{2k-2} = n_{2k - 1}, \text{ or } \\
             &          && n_{2k-4} > n_{2k-3} = n_{2k - 2} = n_{2k - 1}, \text{ or } \\
             &          && \text{...and so on, alternating leading inequality until...} \\
             &          && n_1 < n_2 = n_3 = n_4 = \cdots = n_{2k} \\
n_{2k}       & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Playing this variant is the same as playing a sequence of single-pile Nim games, where the loser of each sub-game goes first in the next game in the sequence. It would also be possible to consider any other sequence of impartial games. For example, you could consider a sequence of multiple-pile Nim games, or a game of Nim, followed by a game of Kayles, followed by another game of Nim.
I would guess that the formula above still applies, but where $n_i$ is the Grundy value of each game (although above $n_i > 0$, but the Grundy value of one of the games in the sequence could be zero despite the game not being over).
I've been unable to find anything about sequences of games like this. A variant called "Black and White" Nim has been considered, but that has different rules. Have sequences of impartial games like this been studied before, and if so, where could I find their analysis?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
